# Only occasional missing data in timed Ajax, PHP, Mysql request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

"work.php" deletes all rows in a mysql db and inserts new data every 5 seconds, this works fine.
"result.php" is displaying the data from the same mysql table, this works fine.
"resultajax.php" refreshes a div every 3 seconds with the db content from result.php, this works fine, the data refreshes and updates correctly.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
 function ()
{
$('#cat').load('result.php #dog');
}, 3000);
```

However, approximately every 7 to 10th refresh of "resultajax.php", the #dog div gets loaded, but without the data from the db. It almost feels like the div is being pulled at the precise moment between the database rows being deleted and before being repopulated, so obviously the db is empty for that brief second. Then 3 seconds later when the div refreshes again, it is fine and continues. That occasional empty page is annoying me and looks messy.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Check if there is data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Check if result.php is returning a blank result. This will require reworking your existing function a little:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'result.php',
            done:function(data){
                var dogData = $(data).find("#dog").html();
                if(dogData != ''){
                    $("#cat").html(dogData);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
```